# Toggling visibility of axis tick labels causes them to be destructed altogether

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Python 3.6 on Win10 Pro (64bit) and recently upgraded to matplotlib version 3.1.2. Upon doing so, I ran into a problem with toggling the visibility of the axis tick labels (as opposed to the tick marks). I include a minimal code fragment that demonstrates the problem.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0, 1], [8, 6])
ax = plt.gca()
yticks = ax.get_yticklabels()
print(yticks)
for tick in yticks:
  tick.set_visible(False)

yticks = ax.get_yticklabels()  
print(yticks)
for tick in yticks:
  tick.set_visible(True)
```

The code snippet generates a plot in which the y tick labels are missing. It also prints how many tick labels are returned by get_yticklabels() prior to and after setting their visibility to False (11 and 0, respectively). It seems as if setting the visibility of the labels to False has removed them altogether.  As a workaround to get the tick labels back, one can set the tick position on the axis via:

```
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
```

I am not sure whether this is the intended behavior but with the previous matplotlib version (I believe it was 3.0.x) this did not occur, nor would I expect it to. Any advice and help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: This was not intended. It bisects to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10088. Please open an issue at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the fast and helpful answer. As instructed, I opened an issue on [github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16197](http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16197).